# undefined local variable or method `resource_class'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Windows 8.1
Ruby 2.0
Rails 4.1
Devise

I am using Devise for users management. I finish the registration process OK, and then I receive an email asking me to confirm. Everything is working like it's supposed to.

The link in the email is the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/confirmation?confirmation_token=2RSshr4nKyL3FUqsvxc1
```

When I click on it, I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `resource_class' for #<ConfirmationsController:0x00000006f7ba88>
```

and it points to line 14 of the conformations controller, which is the following line:

```
def show
  self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have field name `resource_class` in your `confirmations` table? post the confirmations table

Comment: There is no confirmations table. This is Devise and the User table

Comment: ok. where is `resource_class` defined? the error message means the `ConfirmationsController` doesn't have a `resource_class` attribute

Comment: have you inherited the your confirmations controller(say `User::ConfirmationsController`) with `Devise::ConfirmationsController` ?

Comment: ravi1991: I assumed that the devise installer would have taken care of it, but for some reason, the confirmations controller inherited the application controller. I modified it and it's now working fine. If you change this to an answer I will accept it.